# Is it possible to read MSBuild macros of C/C++ project programatically outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to do a mass edit on Visual Studio 2017 projects (`.vcxproj`). This edit depends conditionally on some project properties. Sadly it's more complicated than what could I do using shared `.props` file.

I could reimplement the functions needed to get the macros I want, such as `$(TargetExt)`. But I was wondering if there is some Microsoft build tool that could print the required macro to stdout so that I could do:

```
getMacroValue.exe -project MyProject.vcxproj -value TargetExt
```

Is there anything like that, or some hack/trick that would lead to the same result? I don't mind dirty solution if it works, what I am doing is a one-time thing, but there are 50+ projects to edit with 5mins per edit so writing a script is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sample(C# console app) could help you read the property value from proj file.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    string path = args[0];
    string macro = args[1];

    ProjectCollection collection = new ProjectCollection();
    Project project = new Project(path, null, null, collection, ProjectLoadSettings.IgnoreMissingImports);

    string val = project.GetPropertyValue(macro);
    Console.WriteLine(val);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The problem is MSVC projects are giant abominations of various included projects, conditional properties and so on. Many project properties are also implicitly set even though they are not seen in any of the XML files. I can parse XML, and I did parse some stuff from the project files that way, but it's insuficient.

Comment: After my research, I'm afraid that you can't do that. I found a library called: [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project?view=msbuild-16-netcore), it can also read vcxproj file. But it still has some limitations. such as: 1. cannot read property group with condition. 2. can read props file but you need to explicitly import it in the vcxproj file